# Passing html form's Multiple input value from one input field to a JavaScript event function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to pass two input field value of html form and concatenate them by JavaScript. When I am sending one value and the concat function takes one parameter it is ok. But when sending two value and the concat function takes two parameter it is printing << title.value="Undefined" >> in concat function and is concatenate with user_name. I need to pass the title also from user_name field.

```
   <form  "method="post"action="signup.php">
     <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
      <br/>
        <label>Email:;
       <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onkeyup="concat(this.value,title.value)" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this. Give some name and id name to the form and call concat function like below.

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" "method="post"action="signup.php">
     <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
      <br/>
        <label>Email:;
       <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onkeyup="concat(this.value, form1.title.value)" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Actually I told to give name and id name to the form. I did that. It worked. thanks @JuanMendes

Answer (score 3):

Change `title.value` to `document.getElementById("title").value`.